# Silence "-canOpenURL: failed for URL:"

Tags: ios, ios9

I have added my URL schemes to Info.plist, as required by iOS 9. However, calls result in:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "scheme://" - error: "(null)"
```

being logged to the console. The calls are succeeding and returning the correct value, but these log messages are annoying. How can I disable them?

Comment: You can't. Hopefully they go away with the iOS 9 GM.

Comment: Unfortunately this is on GM.

Comment: Any luck on this? It's pretty annoying having the app logs cluttered up by this.

Comment: Here we are, 2019 and it's still a problem.

Comment: Here we are, 2021 and it's still a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try just using openURL: to check if it can open, since it returns a Bool, then call openURL: again:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: keyword) {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Looks weird to see the same statement repeated twice, but at least it doesn't spit out a failure message like canOpenURL: does. If anyone knows how to make it look less weird, please do tell.

Comment: This opens the URL - I just want to test if it *can* be opened.

Comment: The if statement does not open the URL, it only checks if it can open, silently. You'll have to call openURL: again to actually open it.

Comment: The documentation leans towards it opening the URL, even on the if statement check. Even if it doesn't open it on the simulator, I'd be a little wary of using it like this, it may open on an actual device, or if not then, could easily change in an OS update.